# PSQL - invalid input syntax for type double precision: "null";

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm writing a query to pull some data and running into this invalid input syntax for type double precision: "null" error and am not entirely sure the meaning behind it and/or haven't figured out a solution.  The column I'm running the case statment on does have null values in it or it has the appropriate value that i need.

account id col could have strings or it has null values

I've tried:

```
case
    when length(account_id) > 1
      then account_id
    else
      'null'
    end as account_id,
```

and

```
case
    when account_id is not null
      then account_id
    else
      'null'
    end as account_id,
```

both resulting in Invalid operation: invalid input syntax for type double precision: "null";

When i just put this in a column and use the length(account_id) it will show the length or just display null - why wouldn't this work in a case statement?

Thanks!

Comment: the columns seems to be a numeric data type, and you are using `'null'` as in a string, not as `NULL`

Comment: What's the data type of `account_id`? It's complaining is `double precision`.

Comment: it's a string field - Gordon's answer below worked!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`'null'` is a string.  `null` is . . . well `null`.  Your `account_id` appears to be of type `double precision`.  That is a strange choice for an `account_id`, but inappropriate data types are not relevant.  What is relevant is that the `case` expression wants everything to be of the same type, with numbers getting precedence.

You may want one of these two things:

```
(case when length(account_id) > 1 then account_id end) as account_id,
```

The default is `null` when there is no `else`.  You could add `else null`, but that is redundant.

Or:

```
(case when length(account_id) > 1 then account_id::varchar(255) else 'null' end) as account_id,
```

Comment: I think length() cannot be applied to a numeric value: `ERROR: function length(numeric) does not exist - SQLState:  42883`

Comment: Super. ::varchar(255) helped